# Why won't blocks yield resources on Minecraft (PS4)?

Tags: ps4, minecraft-legacy-console

After a while of playing Minecraft on the PS4, I had decided to take a break, save the game, and turn off my PS4. When I got on a couple of hours later I tried to break blocks in my survival world and it would not give me the resources back!

A particular example of this is when I broke a block of stone and it yielded no cobblestone tile drops. Later on I decided to exit the game without saving and get back on to see if it would work. Unfortunately, it did not.

What can cause this? Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: I would recommend not using texting abbreviations, such as "smh" or "lol". It appears unprofessional, and appearing professional is an important thing on this site, although more often on SO.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you are using the proper tool. Stone requires a pickaxe to mine so if you were using your hands, it will not drop anything.

Comment: So you COULD break blocks, but it didn't give you the stuff? Does it give you resources for dirt?

Comment: Yes, you can break dirt with your bare hands. If dirt isn't dropping, then it is probably another issue.

Comment: It will not give me any reasources when I break dirt, I've tried it a couple of times and it hasn't worked

Answer (score -2):

The only tool type that yields cobblestone from stone is pickaxes. Usin your hands or a shovel or even a shiny diamond sword won’t work, the same logic counts for ores